# Reload module automatically became active without notice and cannot be removed

Tags: reload, trigger.io

It's me again,

I just found out that Reload module became active and there is no way to turn it off. Its nowhere in module lists and so on. Is this some kind of new implementation, because it's not fair to enforce me using a module which I don't want to use.
Also I'm on 2nd type paid account and it costs me dearly for the services I get.
Please respond because I'm loosing precious time because of your fault.

Regards,
Ivan Popjelev

Answer (score 3):

you can disable Reload by unchecking the `core.general.reload` checkbox in the App config section in your Toolkit.

Or, you can edit the `config.json` file to set `reload: false` if you prefer.

If you've migrated an app across from v1.4 to v2.0.0, we respect the Reload setting in the original app: we don't automatically enable Reload during the migration or anything like that.

Comment: When I edit config.json and set reload: false and after I go to the config section in your wonderful site the value of reload is set to true again. Also even if I ucheck module my app still does not get any update after recompiling.